# Getting the first 10-digit prime number using lazy lists in Raku

Tags: primes, lazy-evaluation, raku

I'm trying to get the first 10-digit prime number using the *lazy lists*. Here is my take based on the (already given) code for computing the prime numbers:

```
my @primes = 2,3,5, {first * %% none(@_), (@_[*-1] ... Inf)} ...  -> $s {$s.chars == 10};

say @primes[@primes.elems-1];
```

The problem with that code is that it takes too long to finish.

Is there any quick method to get that first 10-digit prime number?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can make it faster by:

- Starting from the smallest 10 digit number (no point going through a bunch of candidates that would never match even if they are prime)
- Using the fast built-in `is-prime` method rather than a hand-rolled algorithm

Thus getting:

```
say (1_000_000_000..*).first(*.is-prime)
```

Which produces:

```
1000000007
```

You could filter out evens too, but I suspect `is-prime` rejects those as fast as you'd separately test them anyway. (Also, it turns out the number is so close to the first 10-digit number that nothing aside from stating at `1_000_000_000` matters in practice.)